# IDLE3 installed for Python however I can't open it

Tags: python, python-idle, python-3.6

My linux distribution(Opensuse 42.2) comes with python 2.7 already installed, however I installed python3 on top of that. And in order to launch IDLE to run the python3 shell, I was told to install "python3-tools" and then just run "idle3" in terminal to launch the shell. However running "idle3" in terminal only brings up an error message, and I can't find any other suggestions. Any help would be extremely appreciated.

** **I have fixed the problem.** The sources that I found gave me the improper package name. After searching the main-repository for Opensuse, the proper package name for python3 IDLE was "python3-idle".

Comment: Does `python3` work?

Comment: @Ofer Sadan Python3 does work in terminal, I just can ged IDLE to launch the appropriate version of Python.

Comment: Try `python3 -m idlelib` in a console (terminal).  If that does not run IDLE with reasonably current python3, then tkinter and or idlelib are not properly installed in the python3 stdlib.  PS what is the error message?

Comment: Also try `python3 -c "import tkinter"`.  If that fails, IDLE cannot run.